# Memory model comparison between OpenGL and OpenCL and performances for heavy math computation

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I'm reading through the OpenGL and OpenCL specification in order to find few informations about the memory model and how exactly they corresponds to each other.

I'm aware OpenGL and OpenCL use essentially the same memory model. What I struggle to understand however, given the namings don't map 1-to-1 (at least it seems to me in that way) is what exactly can be mapped to what (in terms of terminology) between the two.

Any reference would be appreciated.

Under the assumption we have the same GPU as device for both OpenCL and OpenGL the specific question/questions is/are:

1. How for example VBO actually maps to OpenCL? Does a VBO essentially correspond to a chunk of global memory in the OpenCL terminology?
2. What about OpenGL Texture object? my understanding is that this corresponds exactly to an image object in OpenCL, and they both map to texture memory.
3. What about Shared Storage Buffer Object (specifically in the context of Compute Shaders) what does this corresponds to?

Also, even on this site, I find few debates on which one is more performant (between OpenCL and OpenGL). It seems to me that OpenGL Compute Shaders for example should be preferred over OpenCL kernels only if the nature of the problem maps nicely to something graphics related, OpenCL instead is preferred if you have some heavily numerical which is not necessarily graphics related (such as a heavy simulation for example).

What I struggle a bit to understand is why this is the case given that the memory model, and resources, are essentially the same. Apart from experimenting I wonder what is the actual difference justifying the difference. With specific reference to Compute Shaders I'm aware they allow to implement any algorithm you would be able to implement in OpenCL with OpenGL, so why is there a performance difference then?

The kind of problem I'm thinking of would be some relatively heavy optimisation based on level 3 Blas routines (such as GEMM or GEMV).

How well would OpenGL and OpenCL scale for these kind of problems?

The reason I'm asking is because I struggle a bit to find relatively recent information and benchmarks that might answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

> How for example VBO actually maps to OpenCL

I have limited experience with OpenGL, but in my understanding, many OpenGL objects don't map to OpenCL objects at all. OpenGL in general works at much higher level of abstraction, and it does a whole lot of things in the background for you. OpenCL is significantly simpler, and more low level (which might also explain why OpenCL can sometimes be faster). There are chunks of memory (cl_mem), code (cl_kernel), you launch the kernels that work with the memory - that's pretty much it. There's no complicated internal state machine like in OpenGL.

> With specific reference to Compute Shaders I'm aware they allow to implement any algorithm you would be able to implement in OpenCL with OpenGL

Actually, i think that might be incorrect. OpenCL allows you to do with pointers almost everything you can do in C (arithmetic, reinterpret-casting etc), while GLSL is much more limited (AFAIK).

> what is the actual difference justifying the difference

One huge difference (again AFAIK) is the builtin library of math functions (like sin, cos, etc). OpenGL has them too, but in OpenCL they have guaranteed precision by the standard. This makes a huge difference for scientific applications, OTOH it means the OpenCL kernel can be significantly slower (because an implementation of sin() with high precision on full input range is much more code than some crappy implementation that just gives you reasonably precise values on some very limited input range).

Comment: I didn't think the pointer part OpenGL/OpenGL. But the fact a language doesn't provide a feature doesn't mean you can't implement the same algorithm right on both platforms right? I think however there's some correspondence between some OpenCL objects and OpenGL. My understanding for example is that textures and cl_image objects would use texture memory (assuming you're using a GPU as device). On the compute shader side there's a requirement for the SSBO which can only map to global memory in OpenCL.

Comment: About the state machine side of OpenGL I think you're right but this to me justifies that for very graphics applications you shouldn't be using OpenCL (unless you want to write your own rendering pipeline).

Comment: @user8469759 whether you can implement all algorithms without the pointers - probably, but it might result in messy code. Also i agree, there probably are some corresponding objects between some GL and CL objects - i don't know GL enough to tell you which, sorry. In OpenCL (1.2) with GPU, both cl_mem and cl_image objects are chunks of memory allocated in GPU VRAM, AFAIK the only difference is how they're accessed (cl_image goes through the texturing unit).